# MySQL update multiple rows at once depending on 2 fields

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to optimise some mysql queries on a website, and I've hit a bit of a snag - I currently have (in a loop):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field1` = `field1` + 1 WHERE `field2` = '$some_value' AND `field3` = '$another_value'
```

and I wish to optimise it to perform this all in 1 query - if there was no field3 I know I could use a WHERE `field2` = IN() and I know that I could do the query like:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field1` = `field1` + 1 WHERE (`field2` = '$some_value' AND `field3` = '$another_value') OR (`field2` = '$some_value2' AND `field3` = '$another_value2') OR ...
```

but this is going to be for several thousand rows at once and is very hacky - can anyone think of a solution this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the values for each of your $some_value's are relatively consistent over time, you could turn them into a view, then join against that view to perform the update:

```
UPDATE 
  table 
SET 
  field1 = field1+1 
FROM 
  myFilterView 
WHERE 
  table.field2=myFilterView.field2 AND 
  table.field3=myFilterView.field3
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as field2 and field3 are foreign keys in other tables so going to be different combinations of values in just about every query.

Comment: There is no way you could construct the view to have all of the different combinations represented?  Not even with unions?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table with the new data in it (same exact columns as your original table). After all the inserts are done, then update the table with this data.

```
create temporary table temp (field1 int(5), field2 varchar(10), field3(varchar(10));

insert into t(field1, field2, field3) values (1, "abcd", "abcd"), (2, "efg", "efg"), etc

update tbl inner join t on t.field2 = tbl.field2 and t.field3 = tbl.field3
set tbl.field1 = t.field1 + 1;
```